# Encoding issue when generating SQLite database from .sql file

Tags: sql, sqlite, encoding, utf-8, utf

I am trying to generate a SQLite database from a .sql file. The following line is in my .sql file:

```
INSERT INTO table(text) VALUES('“hello”');
```

I generate the SQLite database with the following command in Terminal:

```
cat output.sql | sqlite3 database.sqlite
```

Unfortunately, in the SQLite database that is generated, the quotes around hello appear as Ò. Why am I experiencing this encoding issue?

Comment: What is the encoding of the .sql file? Are you using the Windows console?